# Return an HTTP fail (e.g. 500) response with JSON body from flask?

Tags: python, http, flask

As of flask 1.1.x, it is easy to return a JSON response body along with an HTTP success code, such as

```py
return {"success": 1, "message": "You did it!"}, 200
```

However, returning an HTTP failure status the same way

```py
return {"success": 0, "message": "You screwed up."}, 400
```

only seems to return a response header and message, (e.g. `HTTP/1.0 INVALID REQUEST`)

The Content-type header (correctly) says `application/json`, but, the body is empty.  This happens for any non-2xx class status code.

Flask documentation implies I should be able to do this, but, nothing I've tried seems to work. This includes creating specialized error handlers like

```py
@app.errorhandler(400)
def custom400(error):
    return jsonify({'message': error})
```

and then calling `abort(400, 'my error message')`, which doesn't work since the `error` argument to the handler isn't the string passed to `abort`, but, is always an error object of whatever type the HTTP error is (e.g. 410 -> `<GONE Gone>`.

Is this "normal" HTTP response behaviour, or is flask doing something weird?

Comment: I see you've used `jsonify` in your specialised route, but did you try `return jsonify({"success": 0, "message": "You screwed up."}), 400` in your normal routes?

Comment: The documentation says that a `dict` return value is turned into a response object using `jsonify`; it doesn't say anything about the individual elements of a tuple return value; I think the implication is that you need to create the correct response object yourself for the first element of the tuple.

Comment: @chepner, tried that, too.

I think my problem ended up being I was setting a breakpoint too early on the client (chrome browser) side in my jquer.ajax call. After I continued execution (thus exiting the `error` handler) I saw that the body had indeed been filled in.  The browser evidently does this after the error handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is more PEBKAC than anything else.  I had set a breakpoint inside my `$.ajax.error` handler, looking at the returned response in the browser (chrome) debug window when the breakpoint fired.

But,the body of the response isn't made available to the debug window until AFTER this handler exists.  Once I continued execution of the `error` handler, the JSON response body is came through as expected.